# I'm trying to run a bot with a parser on a remote server. Everything works on the local machine, and the server issues an error with the web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

14:04 ~/coinMarketCap_scrapingBot $ python bot.py
0
2023-07-29 14:11:08,099 (**init**.py:960 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Infinity polling exception: local variable 'driver' reference
d before assignment"
2023-07-29 14:11:08,100 (**init**.py:962 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sosotastas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/**init**.py", line 955, in infinity_polling
self.polling(non_stop=True, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
File "/home/sosotastas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/**init**.py", line 1043, in polling
self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
File "/home/sosotastas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/**init**.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
raise e
File "/home/sosotastas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/**init**.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
File "/home/sosotastas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
raise self.exception_info
File "/home/sosotastas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 90, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/sosotastas/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/**init**.py", line 6770, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
result = handler'function'
File "/home/sosotastas/coinMarketCap_scrapingBot/bot.py", line 47, in on_start
uptade_the_data(chat_id)
File "/home/sosotastas/coinMarketCap_scrapingBot/bot.py", line 19, in uptade_the_data
main_parser()
File "/home/sosotastas/coinMarketCap_scrapingBot/parser.py", line 61, in main_parser
cards = scrolling_save()
File "/home/sosotastas/coinMarketCap_scrapingBot/parser.py", line 35, in scrolling_save
driver.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment

I tried to upload other versions of the driver to the hosting, the error is the same